# enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock BOOL *stop

Tags: ios, xcode

I think it's funny about the api

```
- (void)enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(KeyType key, ObjectType obj, BOOL *stop))block
```

I noticed the parameter stop.At first,I think it's a type of (BOOL *) I have never seen.But The document says

> Discussion
>   If the block sets *stop to YES, the enumeration stops.

It seems like the parameter called *stop,and I delete * will get an error.

I wonder Why?

Comment: What do you mean by `I delete * will get an error`? I can answer why the paramter is `BOOL *` but I don't understand what do you mean with the second part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a very basic question about the C language on which Objective-C is based. You aren't familiar with pointers?

`stop` is a parameter of the block. Its type is `BOOL*` which means "a pointer to BOOL".

Somewhere within the implementation of `-enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:` is code which calls the block you supllied. That code has created storage for a `BOOL` value. It is passing the pointer to (a.k.a. address of) that storage to your block so that your block may, by writing through the pointer, modify the value at that storage location.

The statement `*stop = YES;` assigns the value `YES` to the `BOOL` pointed to by the `stop` variable. That's what I meant above by "writing through the pointer". In this way, the block has modified a variable of the caller's, which is how the caller knows that the block wants the enumeration to stop.